# How to add contents of "key" to a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have this code (which works just fine):

```
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices1];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices2];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices3];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices4];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices5];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices6];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices7];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices8];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices9];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices10];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices11];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices12];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices13];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices14];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices15];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices16];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices17];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices18];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices19];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices20];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices21];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices22];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices23];
    [customServicesArray addObject: userPreferences.aCustomServices24];

    unsortedCustomArray = customServicesArray;
```

that I'm trying to "streamline" by using this code:

```
    unsortedCustomArray = [NSMutableArray new];  //  initialize the array
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userPreferences.aCustomServices%u",i+1];
    }
```

I want the "contents" of userPreferences.aCustomServices*n* in the array, but what I'm getting is this in the array:

```
userPreferences.aCustomServices1,
userPreferences.aCustomServices2,
userPreferences.aCustomServices3,
userPreferences.aCustomServices4,
userPreferences.aCustomServices5,
userPreferences.aCustomServices6,
userPreferences.aCustomServices7,
userPreferences.aCustomServices8,
userPreferences.aCustomServices9,
... and so on...
```

How do I change the code so it adds the *contents* of the userPreferences.aCustomServices objects?

Comment: Why do you have 24 separate properties like that? Why not use an array?

Comment: They are attributes of a CoreData entity...

Comment: Do you want a NSMutabledictionary instead of a NSMutableArray?

Comment: If I did that, I would have to convert the dictionary to an array... is that *easily* done?

Comment: I found this:  NSArray * values = [dictionary allValues];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use KVC:

```
[customServicesArray addObject:[userPreferences valueForKey:key]];
```

but you need to change your key generation to:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"aCustomServices%u",i+1];
```

Comment: Unknown exception: valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity PreferenceData is not key value coding-compliant for the key "userPreferences.aCustomServices1".'     
PreferenceData is a CoreData entity; CustomServices are attributes of PrefgerenceData... (I guess I should have included that... sorry) :-{